# Python: Uexpected an indented block

Tags: python, optimization, syntax-error, space, ident

I am not sure why I am getting this error.

**I am getting this error:
Error on line 24:
    tempmax = ans
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block**

Here what I´ve have so far:

````
 def __init__(self, init_name, init_population, init_voters):
  self.name = init_name
  self.population = init_population
  self.voters = init_voters

def get_init_population(self):
 return self.population

def get_init_voters(self):
 return self.voters

def get_name(self):
 return self.name

def highest_turnout(data):
 tempcounty = ""
 tempmax = 0

for county in data:
 ans = (county.get_init_voters()/county.get_init_population())
 if ans > tempmax:

tempmax = ans
tempcounty = county
 return [(tempcounty.get_name(), tempmax)]

allegheny = County("allegheny", 1000490, 645469)
philadelphia = County("philadelphia", 1134081, 539069)
montgomery = County("montgomery", 568952, 399591)
lancaster = County("lancaster", 345367, 230278)
delaware = County("delaware", 414031, 284538)
chester = County("chester", 319919, 230823)
bucks = County("bucks", 444149, 319816)
data = [allegheny, philadelphia, montgomery, lancaster, delaware, chester, bucks]
result = highest_turnout(data) # do not change this line!
print(result) # prints the output of the function

# do not remove this line!```
````

Comment: your formatting is kinda off here, python is generally indented with 4 spaces and it looks like your for loop, if, and return are not properly indented

Comment: If you don't know why that line causes an indentation error, then you have skipped learning the basics of Python.

Comment: If you use four spaces for indentation, it makes it easier to *see** the indentation level.  Please fix the formatting. 
.. [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) ... [more Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) ... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: Because, as the error message states, the block starting with `tempmax = ...' should be indented. Also, you should respect the convention of using 4 spaces for indents in Python, that would make the structure of your code and the different levels easier to distinguish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The indentation is not correct, try:

```py
class County:
    def __init__(self, init_name, init_population, init_voters):
        self.name = init_name
        self.population = init_population
        self.voters = init_voters

    def get_init_population(self):
        return self.population

    def get_init_voters(self):
        return self.voters

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name


def highest_turnout(data):
    tempcounty = ""
    tempmax = 0
    for county in data:
        ans = (county.get_init_voters()/county.get_init_population())
        if ans > tempmax:
            tempmax = ans
            tempcounty = county
    return [(tempcounty.get_name(), tempmax)]

allegheny = County("allegheny", 1000490, 645469)
philadelphia = County("philadelphia", 1134081, 539069)
montgomery = County("montgomery", 568952, 399591)
lancaster = County("lancaster", 345367, 230278)
delaware = County("delaware", 414031, 284538)
chester = County("chester", 319919, 230823)
bucks = County("bucks", 444149, 319816)
data = [allegheny, philadelphia, montgomery, lancaster, delaware, chester, bucks]
result = highest_turnout(data) # do not change this line!
print(result) # prints the output of the function
```

Output:

```
[('chester', 0.7215045058280377)]
```

Comment: Thank you. I am now getting this error: Error on line 34:
    result = highest_turnout(data) # do not change this line!
Error on line 20:
    ans = (county.get_init_voters()/county.get_init_population())
AttributeError: 'County' object has no attribute 'get_init_voters'

Comment: is highest_turnout supposed to be part of the class or is it a separate function?

Comment: @ElmerGustavoReyesAltamirano I updated the answer with the fully indented class and added `highest_turnout()` as a `@staticmethod` so you call it like `County.highest_turnout()`. Do you need all the `get_` methods? you can just do `allegheny.voters` and it will give you the same thing as `allegheny.get_voters()`

Comment: So I need it so: Expected method 'highest_turnout' to be defined as:

def highest_turnout(data):

Comment: @ElmerGustavoReyesAltamirano like that?